# bat file execute at startup

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file. this is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('curl -X GET http://my.host.address') do (set response=%%a)

IF "%response:~0,3%" == "Sat" (goto close)
IF "%response:~0,3%" == "Sun" (goto close)
goto open    

:open
    start "" "D:\my\folder\app1.exe"
    start "" "D:\my\other\folder\app2.exe"
    goto close

:close
    pause
    exit

:nothing
```

the problem is, sometimes it says "Cant find app1.exe", sometimes it works. I put a shortcut to this bat file in startup folder, to make it run everytime the computer starts up. what am I doing wrong here? also, how do I know if the url called with curl returns an OK response, how do the script handle if there's any problem with the call?

Comment: Well, it looks like the problem is that it can't find the file `D:\my\folder\app1.exe`. Is it possible that D: is a network drive that has not gotten mapped by the time the batch file is run?

Comment: @CodyGray : no, D:\ is local drive. but if it cant find said folder, it should fail everytime, not sometimes, right? this is really confusing.

Comment: @Thomas Exactly the posted batch code fails sometimes to start `app1.exe` from local hard disk drive `D:`? Does your real batch file look different?

Comment: @Mofi : well, that's just the test folder. if I run the batch file some time after startup, it works just fine. but if it's run on startup, it'd fail